# R. not giving me array option

Tags: android, xml

Im trying to read an array from my strings.xml to my code but R. is not giving me the array option, maybe it has something to do with the package? for example when i tried android.R it gave me a array option but I couldnt find the name of the strings-array object i created in xml.

Here is my code:

```
this.context = context;
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    thumbnailNames = res.getStringArray(R.array.thumbnail);
```

here is my xml file:

```
<string name="app_name">Wallpapers: Art of Autism</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="donate_sidebar">Donate for Charity</string>
<string name="who_sidebar">Who are we?</string>
<string name="mission_sidebar">What is our mission?</string>
<string name="autism_sidebar">What is autism?</string>
<string name="developer_sidebar">About the developer</string>
<string name="categories_main">Categories:</string>
<string name="aoaart_main">AoAart</string>
<string name="featured_radiobtn">Our Favorites</string>
<string name="abstract_radiobtn">Abstract Art</string>
<string name="scenery_radiobtn">Scenery</string>
<string name="animals_radiobtn">Animals</string>
<string-array name = "thumbnail">
    <item >one</item>
     <item >two</item>
      <item >three</item>
       <item >four</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: yes it was a typo, when i hit "." after R it doesnt give me the option for array

Comment: instead of import android.R you have to import yourpackagename.R.

Comment: make sure you imported packegename.R (not android.R).

Comment: still not getting array, i can do R.strings.animals_radiobutton and everyother option in my strings.xml but i cant access my array list

Comment: make sure you saved your string file..

Comment: try `Clean` your project.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

When you import **android.R** which provide android default resource.

In you case you have define your custom array in string so you can access your custom resources using **YourPackageName.R** reference so try to import **YourPackageName.R** instead of **android.R**

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [Can't get array string resource from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796851/cant-get-array-string-resource-from-xml)

wasnt compiling, so i just changed the name of my strings.xml file and clean build and then changed it back and clean build